# Finding password length using Airmon-ng and Crunch on Kali Linux [WPA/WPA2]

Tags: wifi, password-cracking, aircrack-ng

I want to find the length of a password on my wireless network.

How can I monitor/track the behavior of the WiFi reaction to entering the current password?

Once I find the exact length of the required password I can start trying all possible combinations

I also have the source code for the airodump-ng file in C. Maybe I can edit functionality to support pattern finding? I know several programming languages and am great at programming so wondering if this is another side I can go by?

Comment: Wireless network

Comment: The encryption method is done by WPA/WPA2. Its just password cracking for any wireless network. But I am trying this on my own network to make sure the algorithm works

Comment: I am trying to CRACK a password which is under the WEP, WPA, WPA2 protocols

Comment: WPA/WPA2 is an encryption method. Ofcourse it is related to passwords because there is a pre-shared key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I monitor/track the behavior of the WiFi reaction to entering the current password?

You cannot determine the pre-shared key length from observing the network traffic.

There is no "*WiFi reaction to entering the current password*" because when a user enters the key (password) on their machine the communication does not yet take place.

The pre-shared key is used to derive a master key which is a local operation on both ends. After that, all further key derivation-operations use fixed-length keys and do not have any "knowledge" about the length of the "initial" pre-shared key.

Comment: I'm aware I can brute force the PSK. I use a long dictionary for that however the issue is that it will take a LONG time to determine the PSK since i have to check EVERY password length. So for EVERY password length i have to check all possible combinations in the long dictionary. Algorithmic complexity time will be VERY inefficient. That is the real issue..... hence why I'm trying to find the correct length. I have tried this using aircrack-ng and a long dictionary file.  Haven't used crunch but that is an option

Comment: @geforce You say that if it was a bad thing that wpa2 is so hard to crack...